# Confusion about constructors - expected a ';'

Tags: c++, class

Instead of putting my class in the same file as my main function, I'm trying to use a #include. Though, when I do this, I get an error for my constructor. This is my input.cpp file:

```
#ifndef input
#define input
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class input
{
public:
    input(int sent)
    {
        s = sent;
    }

    void read();
    void store(string s);

private:

    int s;

};
#endif
```

This is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "input.cpp"



int main()
{

    cout<<"Hello, please enter your input"<<endl;
    string sent;
    getline(cin, sent);
    cout<<sent;

    input1 *newinput = new input1("hello");




    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> "intelliSense expected a ';'"

in the body of my constructor. Though, when I copy / paste the class directly into my main.cpp file, the error goes away. Any idea on what is causing this?

Comment: You define class `input` but you use class `input1`.

Comment: IntelliSense "errors" arent related to compilation in any way.

Comment: You don't want to include .cpp files, so you know. You should only be including header files really, which contains things like prototypes (whilst your cpp will contain the implementation).

Answer (score 2):

1. Do no use `using namespace` in headers
2. You have `input` as macro constant and name of class is the same. I afraid it's the root your problem.
3. Prefer to use constructor initialization lists  `input(int sent) : s(sent) {}`

UPDT

you may need constructor able to accept string as parameter `input(const std::string& str1) : str(str1) {}` where `str` is class member to handle string data.

Comment: Why should i not use namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the constructor as having one parameter of type int

```
input(int sent)
{
    s = sent;
}
```

but try to call it passing as an argument a string literal

```
input *newinput = new input("hello");
```

The string literal that has type `const char[6]` can not be implicitly converted to type int and the class has no other constructor that accepts character arrays as arguments.

`EDIT:` You changed you original post several times so it is not clear now whether using name `input1` in stateent

input1 *newinput = new input1("hello");

is a typo or it is some other type.

Also you have a macro definition with the same name as the class name

```
#ifndef input
#define input
```

Change either the macro name or the class name.

Comment: Sorry, input1 was a typo and I fixed it. I got the program running now!